# jQuery waterwheel not showing in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Hi I am having an issue with a jQuery Waterwheel not showing up in Internet Explorer 11,

It works fine in Chrome, Firefox but shows nothing in IE

Been looking at the code for hours and haven't got any closer to solving the issue,

This is the js in the head of the document

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/hover.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.waterwheelCarousel.js"></script>
<script src="js/hover.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
      // include options like this:
      // (use quotes only for string values, and no trailing comma after last option)
      // option: value,
      // option: value
        });
      });
    </script> 

    <!--Javascript for tooltip plugin-->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
            });
     </script>
```

The code I am referencing is the carousel

The CSS Related

```
#carousel {
    width:1105px;
    height:440px;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;

  }
  #carousel img {
    visibility:hidden; /* hide images until carousel can handle them */
    cursor:pointer; /* otherwise it's not as obvious items can be clicked */
  }
```

Here is the HTML that I am using

```
    <!--Start of Carousel-->
   <div id="carousel">
  <a href="#"><img width=" 400" height="250"        src="images/gallery/project/picture.png" id="item-1" /></a>
<a href="#"><img width=" 400" height="250"           src="images/gallery/project/picture.png" id="item-2" /></a>
</div>
```

I am a bit lost as to why it shows in all other browsers and not IE.

Comment: Have you checked the JS error console? (Use `[F12]` to bring up IE’s developer tools.)

Comment: I got this in the error console 
Object doesn't support property or method 'waterwheelCarousel'

Comment: you have duplicate script declarations in your markup, is that deliberate?

Comment: <!--Javascript for tooltip plugin-->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.tooltip').tooltipster();
            });
     </script>

This code isn't related to the waterwheel but I figured i'd include it in case that was breaking it.

Comment: do you have <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of your html?